# OneNote 2010 code cannot be properly pasted back into XAML

Tags: xaml, onenote

Does anyone else experience this?
If I want to paste code from OneNote2010 it does simply not work.

Reproduction: Create any WPF app, copy the XAML into OneNote2010, copy it back -> Whitespace issues.

Or use this sample:

```
<Popup Placement="Center" IsOpen="{Binding Error, Converter={StaticResource StringBoolConverter}}" PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <userControls:ErrorMessageControl></userControls:ErrorMessageControl>
    </Popup>
```

After putting it into OneNote and copying it back it gets broken. I can't even paste it here as it never gets displayed.

Pasting it in XAML creates messages like

> Error 1   " " is not valid in a name. MainWindow.xaml 94
>
> Error 2   White space is missing. MainWindow.xaml 94

Seems like many whitespaces are odd for the editor.

I've compared the pasted code in Notepad++ and displayed non printable characters and I do not to see any issues with the whitespaces.

Comment: Works OK for me. I have my OneNote set up to paste "Text Only" as default. Maybe that's the difference?

Comment: I seem to be unable to locate this entry in the paste-options of my localized version. Could you provide me a hint or screenshot with the option?

Comment: See my answer (had to use anwer option to be able to attach an image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set paste option to "Text Only" when pasting into OneNote.

When pasting, open the menu and select "Text Only"; then open the menu again and set it as default paste.

[image: Paste Options with "Set as default" highlighted]

If the menu is not shown when pasting, go to File -> Options -> Advanced, then in "Editing" group make sure that "Show Paste Options button when content is pasted" is checked.

Comment: I tend to manage lot of things in OneNote and the syntax highlighting which is pasted too when copying code from Visual Studio is quite important for me. I've tested your approach and I can indeed paste this code back and it works, however it's too bad that I cannot preserve the highlighting in that way as I already have hundreds of code snippets in OneNote and copy pasting them to notepad and then to VS does not work either.

Comment: Maybe you can paste all snippets to another page/notebook without formatting and then paste to VS?

Comment: Tested the copy&paste twice. Did not work. It seems that pasting formatted code to OneNote replaces the standard 0x20 whitespace char with 0xA0 which is a non-breaking space. I could paste the code and replace 0xA0 explicitly with 0x20 which works but is quite cumbersome. Too bad OneNote does not support replace...

Comment: After I started getting build errors I tried a bunch of things to get rid of whatever invisible text is causing this problem in my SQL, but could not get it to work.  Tried pasting back into OneNote again As Text and then bringing it back over, no dice.  My only option is to scrap all this code and redo it by hand.  Thanks again, Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to **save formatting**, you may use a workaround:

1. Paste text to the **GoogleDocuments** first
2. Copy this text
3. Paste to the **OneNote**

Good luck.
If someone knows better solution - please share it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OneNote seems to be replacing spaces with non-breaking spaces (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which is a different character.

I came up with this solution adding a script in AutoHotKey https://autohotkey.com

```
#Persistent
return

OnClipboardChange:
 if WinActive("ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE")
 {
   nbs:=chr(160)
   StringReplace, Clipboard, Clipboard, %nbs%, %A_SPACE%, All  
 }
return
```

This is what it does: If AutoHotKey detects a clipboard change (for example you copied text from OneNote) and the active window is onenote.exe, then all non-breaking spaces (char 160 decimal) are replaced with normal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Using Samuel's comment in the XAMeLi's response I was able to resolve this using Notepad++.  Here's how:

1. Open the file (in my case it's a SQL file.  You can actually see the
   goofy non-breaking spaces in SSMS) using Notepad++.
2. Open the ["Converter" plugin by Don Ho](http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/f5d13754/#7656) (really?), "Conversion Panel"
   menu item.
3. Go to the "Hexadecimal" textbox and type "A0". To the right of the
   "Ascii" textbox hit the "Copy" button.
4. In Notepad hit Ctrl-H to "Find and Replace". In the "Find" textbox
   hit CTRL-V to paste in your ASCII code there.
5. Go back to the Conversion Panel.  Type "20" into the "Hexadecimal"
   textbox.  Again hit the "Copy" button to the right of the "ASCII"
   textbox. Go back to your Find/Replace dialog and click on the
   "Replace" textbox.  Hit CTRL-V to paste the space there (you
   probably could get away with just hitting the spacebar but I'm
   taking no chances here). Make sure "Match whole word only" is turned
   OFF. Hit the "Replace All" button

Your text should be repaired.  Copy it all, then paste it back into your VS editor and try to build.

Answer (score 0):

...an impromptu solution could be to select one of the non-breaking spaces in SQL studio editor and search and replace them all with a space.